# Android studio not finding sharedPreferences xml

Tags: android, android-studio

Here is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    EditText name;
    EditText phone;
    public static final String nameKey = "nameKey";
    public static final String phoneKey = "phoneKey";
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameText);
        phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phoneText);
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MySharedPreMain", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        if (sharedPreferences.contains(nameKey)) {
            name.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(nameKey, ""));
        }

        if(sharedPreferences.contains(phoneKey)) {
            phone.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(phoneKey, ""));
        }


    }
    public void save(View v){
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor =  sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(nameKey, name.getText().toString());
        editor.putString(phoneKey, phone.getText().toString());
        editor.commit();
        Toast.makeText(this,"data saved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

But some reason why I run the emulation and check to find that has a similar name to my project it is not there.

Can someone help, my file is called mysharedpreferences but all I find is com files.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with the emulator, better use `getDefaultSharedPreferences`

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
Boolean boolean = prefs.getBoolean("YOUR_BOOLEAN_VARIABLE", default_value);

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putInt("YOUR_VARIABLE_NAME", integer_value);
editor.commit();
```

It is quite easy. To retrieve a value, use prefs.getWhatever.  And to write you have to obtain an editor with preferences.edit(); and finally always make a commit().

Comment: Never used getdefaultsharedprefernces. How would I implement it?